Why is Aunt May holding a baseball bat in this scene?
Along with Miles Morales and Gwen Stacy in Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Peter Parker from an alternate
universe is standing at Aunt May’s doorstep, prompting her to answer the door.:

Aunt May: You guys are all very sweet, but no more fans today, please.


Holding a bat, she was shocked when she saw Peter Parker.
Why is Aunt May holding a baseball bat in this scene?

Because she's going to hit them with a bat

@Valorum She is Aunt May ? hitting someone ? not fitting to her role.

May hits people occasionally. When the need arises... https://youtu.be/q292IDwEWZ0?si=1F23Gi4e2fE_z-Lk&t=120

In Ultimate Spiderman, Aunt May willingly activated a fighter jet's engine to blast away a villain: https://youtu.be/-pT21IHF3b0?t=137

Hmm. Mary Jane uses Peter's baseball bat a few times. May hits Spider-Man with a vase, hits Vulture with a plate and poisons the Chameleon, but I can't find any examples of her hitting someone with a bat.

@Clockwork - Actually not that bad of a question "Has Aunt May ever killed anyone?"

In the USA, there are two things that most people have in their homes that are often used as improvised weapons in movies and TV: kitchen knives and baseball bats. Whenever you see a person in American TV or movies pick up a kitchen knife or a baseball bat and they are not about to cook or play baseball, it is supposed to tell you that they are scared and they want a weapon to protect themselves from what they are scared of.

The baseball bat is Chekov's gun. We see her wielding it in an earlier scene, presumably to discourage ardent fans from trying to push into the house (memorabilia-hunting, maybe?).
Then, in another deleted scene we see her using the same bat on Tombstone.



